# docker compose map multiple files or directories as volume

Tags: docker-compose, mounted-volumes

I have a few config file that have to be mapped to files inside the container. I want to be able to change these config files on the host and that should reflect in the container. These are basically connection string files that I want to swap without having to rebuild the containers. What I have in my docker-compose.yml is:

```
services:
  portal:
    container_name: portal
    image: portal
    build:
      context: .
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/portal
      - type: volume
        source: ./local/parameters.local.yml
        target: /var/www/portal/s/config/parameters.yml 
      - type: volume
        source: ./portal.conf
        target: /etc/apache2/sites-available/portal.conf
      - awscreds:/root/.aws:ro
```

I fail to get this to work... I saw some examples where they did not supply the type (or instead of volume they made it "bind") but nothing seems to work for me.

If I build the images with `docker compose up`  and then do `docker inspect portal` I can see that it has: "Mounts": []

My final plan is to have a docker-compose.yml that has a service called portal and mounts 2 or more files inside the container(NOT copy so that I can change it on my host at will) as well as a few directories. What is kicking me in the face is the files that have to be mapped into the container.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change `type: volume` to `type: mount`

```
services:
  portal:
    container_name: portal
    image: portal
    build:
      context: .
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/portal
      - type: mount
        source: ./local/parameters.local.yml
        target: /var/www/portal/s/config/parameters.yml 
      - type: mount
        source: ./portal.conf
        target: /etc/apache2/sites-available/portal.conf
      - awscreds:/root/.aws:ro
```

Also, you can add `read-only: true` to both of those mounts if you don't want the services to be able to modify parameters.yml or portal.conf.

Edit: you can also use short form as pKiran shows below. And for anyone using vim to edit mounted files on the host who is confused about their changes not being reflected inside the container: if you don't `set backupcopy=yes`, vim's default saving strategy [will save the file with a different inode](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/15793#issuecomment-135411504), which breaks the mount.

Answer (score 0):

Just mapping should do the job if the files and folders in the lhs exists in your local machine:

```yaml
services:
  portal:
    container_name: portal
    image: portal
    build:
      context: .
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/portal
      - ./local/parameters.local.yml:/var/www/portal/s/config/parameters.yml 
      - ./portal.conf:/etc/apache2/sites-available/portal.conf
      - awscreds:/root/.aws:ro

volumes:
  awscreds:
```